# Как вывести объект C# в Unity консоль

Tags: c#, unity3d

В PHP есть удобная функция `var_dump`, С# изучаю не долго, способы поиска не сработали. Есть что-то подобное тут?

`Console.Write()` не то, что надо. Там `Debug.Log()`, хотя не знаю, есть ли разница

Comment: Debug.Log как и var_dump выводит тип и значение в Console

Comment: а вы переопределяли `ToString()`?

Comment: @animagnoa мне выводит просто Object если напрямую

Comment: @dgzargo как это?

Comment: @shumik_UA а Object это не тип? скинте суда кусок кода в котором вы выводите значение в консоль

Comment: @shumik_UA и да выше dgzargo верно написал.. если вам нужно вывести массив поэлементно то нужно переопределить в ToString() например вот так: foreach (var item in array) { Debug.Log(item.ToString()); } в этом случае в консоль будет выведен каждый элемент соответственно,
по теме можете посмотреть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824899/php-var-dump-in-c-sharp-to-dump-array-or-objects

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе метод, который сделает то, что тебе нужно.
Код не проверял, писал с головы, так что могут быть ошибки.

Сделай его как экстеншн к класу Debug и будет тебе счастье.
Если же закрались баги в коде - исправь сохранив логику.

```
    public static void Logissimo(object obj)  
    {
        string rez = "";

        if (obj is IEnumerable)
        {
            rez = typeof(item).ToString();
            rez += " => { ";

            int count=0;
            for(var item in (obj as IEnumerable) ) 
            { 
                Debug.Log($"[{count++}] {typeof(item)} => {item}; \r\n"); 
            }

            rez += " }";
        } else {
            rez += $"{obj}";
        }

        Debug.Log(rez);
    }
```

оно будет выводить в консоль

- и лист, и аррей, и любой иной перечисляемый тип
- и обычные типы данных

Comment: Но это же не расширение...

Comment: @aepot это метод который я предлагаю закинуть в расширение к  Debug)